# SQL Server Linked Server Catalogs differ for same user depends on machine on which I log

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

As in title. I have two SQL Servers and to both I am connecting by WindowsAuth with my company login:

1. MY_SERVER - where I have general admin rights, which is set on Windows server with same name
2. SAP_SERVER - sap server, to which I have only datareader access to three databases, lets say db1, db2 and db3

Also I can access both of this server in SSMS from my local laptop or be connecting to MY_SERVER Remote Desktop and there connect in SSMS.

When I came to job, there was already set Linked Server from 1 to 2, so:
I was connecting through Remote Desktop Connection to MY_SERVER, where I was opening SSMS and connecting to local SQL Server (MY_SERVER) with WindowsAuth with my company login and I could run example query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM MY_SERVER.db1.dbo.tabA a 
LEFT JOIN SAP_SERVER.db1.dbo.tabB b 
    ON a.col1=b.col1
```

But when I am trying to login in SSMS on my local laptop to MY_SERVER also with WindowsAuth with my company login, I already cannot run

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM MY_SERVER.db.sch.tabA a 
LEFT JOIN SAP_SERVER.db.sch.tabB b 
    ON a.col1=b.col1
```

and I was getting error message, that I need to create Linked Server (???) but as I mentioned it is already created, so I found somewhere that maybe I need to add my login as linkedserver_login, which I did. This partially succeed, because now I am getting other error message:

> The OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "SAP_SERVER" does not contain the table ""db"."sch"."tabB"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

I make little search and I found that when I go to Server Objects/Linked Servers/SAP_SERVER/Catalogs in SSMS (or simply run `sp_catalogs`) the dbs there are different depends if I am checking on local machine or on MY_SERVER Remote Desktop. On Second one I can see db1, db2 and db3 as it should be, but on First one I can see two dbs to which I do not have even normally access while connecting directly to SAP_SERVER (???).

My question is if someone met similiar problem and maybe somehow solved it?

It seems to me that some simple striaghtforward solution could be just adding dbs to Catalog of Linked Server, but I was trying to find on Microsoft Documentation any function to do it and I could not find anything.

Comment: it makes no sense to use: `server1.db.schema.table` if you're already on server1. you can't link against yourself (at least you shouldn't). If you succeed in connecting from your laptop, i'm guessing you actually connect to some other server first. Or it could be that there's a default login specified for the linked server which points somewhere else. What does `select * from sys.servers` returns in SERVER1 and SAP_SERVER returns? Also check `sys.linked_logins` it could be that due to SPN names, your windows user gets lost when connecting through laptop and then the login in linked_logins hits

Comment: Speculating: Perhaps your two linked server connections are using different credentials, if  explicit remote server logins were specified when the linked server connections were created. If not, perhaps the target server trusts the credentials from one of your originating servers, but not the other. I am no expert, so my comments are necessarily vague. *(Does anyone here know how to ask who-am-I across a linked server connection?)*